# Android Camera Orientation Problem

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing android application. In that I have functionality of camera.
I have implemented that and its working fine for me. Only thing is preview of my camera, orientation is not correct its rotated.
Is anybody having solution on that.

Answer (score 0):

Which API are you using? If it's 1.5 or 1.6 (API 4 & API 5) there is a bug about orientation of camera. Do you see 90 degree rotated view? Check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193)

If you are using SurfaceView, there is a possible solution to this problem (let c is your camera object)

```
Camera.Parameters p = c.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
parameters.set("rotation", 90);
c.setParameters(p);
```

Hope it works well for you.

Comment: Hi kenshi, Thanks for such a quick reply.

Comment: Hi kenshi, Thanks for such a quick reply. I am using API level 10 (2.3.3). I tried what you said but its not working.

Comment: Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(1);
  parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
  mm_Camera.setParameters(parameters);
  parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
  parameters.set("rotation", 90);
  mm_Camera.setParameters(parameters);
  mm_Camera.startPreview();

Comment: Hey hi, I got the solution                                                                   if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
   mm_Camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
  }